# Creación de documentos con la librería de mpdf de php

Tags: php, html, mpdf

Soy nuevo usando la librería mpdf de php, estoy buscando generar un proyecto para automatización de unos infomes, sin embargo, me genera un poco de dudas que no creo haber encontrado en la librería ni buscando para solventar ciertos problemas.

El principal es solo el tema de como el contenido se acomoda cuando para a una nueva página, por ejemplo tengo este código plantilla que envío al script que tiene mpdf:

```
<?php

function contenido() {

$contenido= '
    <body>

        <div class="contenido">
            <h1 class="titulo_gothic" id="introduccion">1 INTRODUCCIÓN</h1>

            <p class="parrafos">
             <!-- Varios parragos que completna la primera hoja -->
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="salto_pagina"></div>
        
        <div>
            <h3 class="texto_encabezado_tablas"><span class="negrilla" id="">Tabla 1-1.</span>Resumen información del proyecto</h3>
        </div>
    </body>
';

return $contenido;
```

}
?>

El problema que veo es cuando estoy haciendo el div que contiene el h3, cuando va a la siguiente página, el texto se aparece pegado a la parte superior del pdf generado, lo que me preocupa es que no haya una opción para hacerlo un poco más automatico por que veo que la opción sería agregar manualmente hoja por hoja  de la siguiente manera y son documentos de al rededor de unas 40 hojas:

```
    <div class="contenido">
         <h3 class="texto_encabezado_tablas"><span class="negrilla" id="">Tabla 1-1.</span>Resumen información del proyecto</h3>
    </div>
```

Contenido en ese caso esta parametrizado con marign y un padding para ajustar después de los encabezados y no se superponga al header o al footer.

Agradezco comentarios o sugerencias, lo que busco más adelante es usar unabase de datos con los textos personalizados y dínamicos para que puedan generarse ciertos textos.